# Referrer URL in case if the link was clicked from email

Tags: php

I have a user registration process in which I send an email to the user for email verfication and to activate their account. Now when the `activate link` from the email is clicked, How do I get the referrer that tells me whether or not the user came to the page by clicking the link from the email?

Comment: You don't. The real question is: what do you need the referrer for? You should add a unique token.

Comment: reffer is needed in case to stop allowing them to access the page directly. think it like a hacker point of view. a hacker can write a script to generate random tokens and than use those tokens directly on the url

Comment: And then what? They have verified an account (if they even succeed) and they still would need the password. Big deal. Referers can be easily faked and are under no circumstances to be used for security. If this really is an issue simply invalidate the account after 5 attempts to verify.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Before you generate the email, you generate a unique token for that user. Then you'd append that token to the URL, and the page that does the verification checks the username and the verification token. If they match, then the user has verified their email.

For example, your email would contain a link to `http://www.example.com/process.php?user=foo&validate_token=bar`. Then your `process.php` page would check to make sure that the `foo` user's validation token is actually `bar`. If it is, then the user `foo` has had their email address validated.

Comment: yes i exactly do like u said, but when user is on that page he can write a script or whatever to generate random tokens and access that url, you know how the hackers are ;)

Comment: Why would they do that? the complexity FAR outweighs the simplicity of creating their own account with a fake email address

Comment: in this sample, the "hacker" would have to randomly guess the username AND id token.

Comment: God knows why they would do that :) but i need maximum protection

Comment: If you really would need maximum protection you would have to use hardware token generators. :-)

Comment: so i needed to make the token as much strong as possible. what can be the best possible generation of token ?? a hash of timestamp ??

Comment: For maximum protection enforce users to create a private certificate, make them upload the public key to your site, give them your site's public key and then use SSL/TLS encryption only via these keys. Your user will be identified *and* the communication is secured. Brute-forcing this would be overkill. Most browsers support client certificates. Apart from that, never use plain-text usernames for such URLs.

Comment: Answer is very close to my requirmenet but i dont know how  append server url http://www.example.com/process.php?user=foo&validate_token=bar, I have tried http://google.com/#http://localhost/test/process.php?user=token. if you see i am appending url with # but it didnt work me

Comment: Any mechanism we can determine whether a request is received by a user or some email analysis platform?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to generate some type of id and store it in a database along with the user info. When the user click on the link, it will have the unique id appended to it like:

```
http://www.mygreatsite.com/verify?user=username&id=1234
```

You'll check the id against any existing id's in the db and if it's a match, allow them in

Answer (score 0):

You can't trust referrers in any way. There are a lot of private browsing plugins and other things that will prevent the referrer from being passed in correctly.

Answer (score 0):

The issue with an email link for registrations, regardless of the token, is that, if you access your db immediately upon activation of the link it is easy enough for some tedious person to create a Denial of Service issue. Simple solution I have designed: check ip address, relocate to different servers based on ip address (aka dump all, or most, of the trouble makers into one location to sort through) and then present  a form to click (or a recapture) to finalise registration before you go anywhere near your db. Not enough by itself but is a handy additional series of walls to add to your other security measures to prevent dns attacks from simulated 'registration' links. Also protects most of your legitimate people from being bothered during an attempted DNS attack.

Comment: Hey, Welcome to SO...!!! Instead of writing a whole paragraph do mention your answer in  listing or bullet format for better reading