# Is it possible to detect spammy traffic from E-Mail, SMS?

Tags: php, http-referer

I need to detect if people are linking to my site from e-mails and SMS. Basically I'm trying to detect spammy traffic and redirect it away.

```
$referer = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
$flags = array('twitter', 'facebook', 'craigslist', 'gumtree');
if (strposa($referer, $flags, 1))
{
    header('Location: '.$link);
}
```

Is it possible to do that? If it's not possible to guarantee detection, how can I do my best to detect it?

Comment: I think I'm talking about http-referers here. In other words, voluntary compliance by websites and servers. What do the referers from SMS and Email tend to look like?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Referrer URL in case if the link was clicked from email](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9186269/referrer-url-in-case-if-the-link-was-clicked-from-email)

Comment: I feel like 'spammy traffic' is pretty broad.. Could you clarify this a bit more?

Comment: on another subject that might matter, `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` might not guaranty to be set and an alternative of `strposa` might be `in_array()`?